# Power Bi - Cannot find column in a DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop

I am a newbie in PowerBi and I am trying to create a DAX in order to compare a column with different variables in order to attribute some values in order to do some conditional formatting of the cells.

I read that I must had a MIN(), MAX(), ... in the expression but I just want to compare for each value not with the maximum.

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help and your time

Comment: Actually using MIN or MAX in that respect has nothing to do with the minimum or maximum value in the referenced column. It is simply used to generate a reference to the value in the current row context.

Comment: So I should use it in my formula ?

Comment: Yes. Also, it's often preferable to use VAR statements at the start of your code to avoid repetition and to make it easier to read/debug.

Comment: If you want to compare each value you need a row context. Put the formula into a calculated column, not measure, or use an iterator function.

Comment: @FrenchHandStand Get the habit of never repeating codes. Put them in a variable  as the men above said. Also If you have multiple conditions, switch() function is much better and more efficient to use.

Comment: and the logical order of your conditions is also incorrect. It must be in reverse order.